# Block btn until at least 1 checkbox of an offset is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

A little frustrated here, somehow I can't make this work no matter what I try. I have a small form with 2 offsets, each containing a few checkboxes as the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test1" /><label for="test1">
```

I need to make sure the user selects at least one of them in each offset in order to be able to click this button, otherwise it should be **unclickable** :)

```
<div class="offset6">
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="#openModal">CONTINUAR<span class="btn_caret"></a>
</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the number of offsets fixed? And how will they be identified, always "offset1" to "offset5"? And just to be sure, there is only one button right?

Comment: Hey musefan, yes they are fixed. Offset3 has 4 checkboxes and Offset8 has 2. There is only one button, which opens a modal. This button can't be clicked until checkboxes are selected... I've tried both answers and they don't do it for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @So it is always "offset3" and "offset8"? And you need at least one checked in both offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
//listen for changes to any checkbox so we can re-evaluate the button state
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    validateInput();
});

//checks to see if the button should be enabled or not
function validateInput(){
    //get the count of checked items in each of the offsets
    var offset3Count = $(".offset3").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    var offset8Count = $(".offset8").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

    //set the disabled state of the button based on the offset counts
    $(".btn").prop("disabled", offset3Count == 0 || offset8Count == 0);
}

//call the function on page load to ensure the button is initially disabled
validateInput();
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/krLSX/) (I had to change your HTML a bit as it was invalid)

---

If you need a specific `.btn`, as in the one in `offset6`, then use this line instead:

```
$(".offset6 .btn").prop("disabled", offset3Count == 0 || offset8Count == 0);
```

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/krLSX/1/)

---

A quick recommendation: If you have unique elements then consider using an `id` attribute for them. For example:

```
<button id="btn6" ...>
```

With the following JQuery selector:

```
$("#btn6")...
```

Comment: Awesome. Only thing missing is I can't open my modal!

Comment: @inkyotogrand: You need to use your orginal HTML, if it is an `<a>` tag you want to disable [then try this instead](http://jsfiddle.net/krLSX/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var chk = $(".offset3,.offset8").find('input[type="checkbox"]'); //cache your selector
chk.change(function () {
    $('div.offset6 a.btn.btn-warning[href="#openModal"]').prop('disabled', chk.filter(':checked').length);
});
```

---

`chk.filter(':checked').length` get length of checked checboxes

---

```
$('.btn').prop('disabled', $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
```

---

Updated After OP's Comment

```
$('div.offset6 a.btn.btn-warning[href="#openModal"]').prop('disabled', $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
```

---

or add and `id` to than use `#` id-selector

Comment: Doesn't work, Tushar. There are many other '.btn' in my code, I need to tag the above-mentioned specifically.